# FileHelper Reading TXT File

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Could you please help me with reading the txt file which is shown in the image below?

[image]

```
 [DelimitedRecord("│")]
public class Orders
{
    public int Belegnr { get; set; }

    public string Pos { get; set; }

    public string Belegdatum { get; set; }

    public string Auftrag { get; set; }
}
 var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();

        if (engine.Options.FieldCount==19)
        {
            var records = engine.ReadFile(@"\\bosch.com\dfsrb\dfstr\div\dc\BUP2_TEF_Share\02_TEF3\90_Projeler\Pems\Maliyetler\KOB1_Order.XML");
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(record.Belegnr);

            }
        }
```

I don't want to read the first 20 rows in the txt file.

Those are info rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **IgnoreFirst** attribute which indicates the numbers of lines to be ignored at the beginning of a file or stream when the engine reads it.

```
[IgnoreFirst(20)] 
[DelimitedRecord("│")]
public class Orders
{ 
  // etc...
}
```

There is also an **IgnoreLast** attribute for ignoring the last rows of the file.

Comment: thank you for your help just one more question how can I ignore any rows with out "│"?

I don't need to any rows w/o this delimiter "│". Is there any way?

thank you

Comment: You can use `[ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.IncludeIfBegins, "|")]`. See [the docs](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/FileHelpers-Stable/FileHelpers/RecordCondition)